# weird obj logo appears for no reason

Tags: angular

My `app.component.html` is:

```
<app-data-table [data]="data" [tableInfo]="productOrderInfo" (modified)="onModification($event)">
</app-data-table>￼
```

My `data-table.html` is completely empty and still this obj sign appears.

The html of the component is empty.
[image]

My `data.table.component.ts` (I don't think it's relevant but here it is):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChildren, QueryList, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ComponentRef } from '@angular/core'; import { EditableValueComponent } from '../editable-value/editable-value.component'; import { ColumnInfo, TableInfo } from '../editable-value/editable-type'; import { MatTableDataSource, MatTable, MatSort, MatPaginator, MatDialog } from '@angular/material'; import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections'; import * as Lodash from 'lodash'; import { EditableOpenObjectComponent } from '../editable-value/editable-object/editable-open-object/editable-open-object.component';


export class TableInsert {   constructor(public rows: object) { } }

export class TableDelete {   constructor(public rows: object[]) { } }

export class TableUpdate {   constructor(public row: object, public column: string, public value: any) { } }

export class TableFeatures {   sort?: boolean;   filter?: boolean;   edit?: Array<string> | boolean;   select?: boolean;   insert?: boolean;   delete?: boolean;   save?: boolean;   close?: boolean;   header?: boolean;   pagination?: boolean; }

@Component({   selector: 'app-data-table',   templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',   styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.scss'] }) export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {   @ViewChildren('editableValue') editableValues: QueryList<any>;   @ViewChild(MatTable, { static: true }) table: MatTable<any>;   @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  @Input() tableInfo: TableInfo;   @Output() modified = new EventEmitter<TableUpdate | TableInsert | TableDelete>();   @Output() save = new EventEmitter<object[]>();   @Output() cancel = new EventEmitter<object[]>();

  defaultFeatures: TableFeatures;   dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);   selection = new SelectionModel<any>(true, []);

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.defaultFeatures = {
      sort: true,
      filter: true,
      pagination: true,
      edit: true,
      select: true,
      insert: true,
      delete: true,
      close: false,
      save: false,
      header: true,
    };   }

  @Input() set data(data: object[] | Promise<object[]>) {
    // data = Promise.resolve(data);
    // data.then(data2 => {
    //   this.dataSource.data = data2 === undefined ? [] : data2
    // });   }

  get data() {
    return this.dataSource.data;   }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.dataSource.data);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator, 0);
    this.tableInfo.features = Object.assign({}, this.defaultFeatures, this.tableInfo.features);   }


  onSave() {
    this.save.emit(this.data as object[]);   }

  onCellClick(editableValue: EditableValueComponent, column: string) {
    if (
      this.openedEditableValue === undefined &&
      this.tableInfo.features.edit !== false &&
      (this.tableInfo.features.edit === true || (this.tableInfo.features.edit as any).indexOf(column) > -1)
    ) {
      editableValue.open = true;
    }   }

  onUpdate(row: object, column: string, value: any) {
    const update = new TableUpdate(Lodash.clone(row), column, value);
    row[column] = value;
    this.modified.emit(update);   }

  onInsert() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditableOpenObjectComponent, {
      width: '320px',
      data: { value: {}, typeInfo: this.tableInfo.columnInfo, title: 'Insert' },
      autoFocus: false,
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result !== undefined) {
        this.dataSource.data.unshift(result);
        this.modified.emit(new TableInsert(result));
      }
      this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data;
    });   }

  onDelete() {
    this.selection.selected.forEach((selected: object) => {
      this.dataSource.data.splice(this.dataSource.data.indexOf(selected), 1);
    });

    this.modified.emit(new TableDelete(this.selection.selected));

    this.selection.clear();
    this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data;   }

  onModification(row: object, column: string, modification: any) {
    this.modified.emit(new TableUpdate(row, column, modification));   }

  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;   }

  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
      this.selection.clear() :
      this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));   }

  get columnsWithSelect() {
    const columns = this.tableInfo.columnInfo.map(columnInfo => columnInfo.name);
    if (this.tableInfo.features.select) {
      columns.unshift('select');
    }

    return ['name'];   }

  get openedEditableValue(): any {
    let editableValue2: any;

    this.editableValues.forEach(editableValue => {
      if (editableValue.open === true) {
        editableValue2 = editableValue;
      }
    });

    return editableValue2;   }


  getDataSource() {
    console.log('abc');
    return new MatTableDataSource([]);   }

}
```

I don't understand how could this sign appear since my data-table.component.html is completely empty. If I add something to the html file it appears and the obj logo appears as well.

If you really want to see my data-table.component.html here it is:
[image]

Comment: Could you share app-data-table component.ts and html?

Comment: the html file is completely empty and I don't do anything special in the component.ts

Comment: kindly share the `app-data-table component.html` as well

Comment: it is COMPLETELY empty nothing to share there. No space, no empty lines nothing. And if I add something to it appears but the obj sign appears after no matter what I add.

Comment: In the code you shared, after the `app-data-table` closing tag, you have some character. I think that might be it ( actually I'm pretty confident) .

Comment: Yes! thank you, that's it. Actually I can't see any character in the code I shared... nor in the editor... very weird. On windows I can see but not in ubuntu whatever.....